# Finding the general expression of an equation describing the monthly payments of a loan

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

In my math textbook (Mathematical Methods by James Nearing) there is this problem:

If you borrow $200,000 pay it back in monthly installments over 30 years at an annual interest rate of 6%, what is your monthly payment and what is the total money that you have paid (neglecting inflation)? To start, you have N payments p with monthly interest i and after all N payments your unpaid balance must reach zero. The initial loan is L and you pay at the end of each month.

Then it gives this equation and tells me to carry on and find the general expression for the monthly payment:

$\Bigl(\bigl(L(1+i)-p\bigr)(1+i)-p\Bigr)\bigl(1+i\bigr)-p\cdot\cdot\cdot N\;times=0$

I'm having difficulty with this because I've never seen a summation in this form, and I don't know where to look for some examples on how to approach this. I'm fairly certain I need to make the summation symbol look like this:
$$\sum_{N=0}^{\infty }(some\;expression\;here)$$I don't see the pattern in the equation I was given. How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the monthly coupon is $C$.  Let $B_i$ be the balance prior to the $i^{th}$ payment, let $P_i$ be the principal paid on the $i^{th}$ payment, and let $I_i$ be the interest paid on the $i^{th}$ payment.  Then:

$$C=P_i+I_i\quad \quad I_i=\frac {.06}{12}\times B_i\quad\quad  B_{i+1}=B_i-P_i$$

Working with the first two payments we see that $$P_2+\frac {.06}{12}\times \left(B_1-P_1\right) = P_1+\frac {.06}{12}\times B_1\implies P_2=(1+\frac {.06}{12})P_1$$  Continuing, we see that $$P_n=(1+\frac {.06}{12})^{n-1}P_1$$  Of course we know that the entire loan is paid off in exactly $360$ payments thus we must have $$\sum_{n=1}^{360}P_n=P_1\times \sum_{n=1}^{360}(1+\frac {.06}{12})^{n-1}=200000$$  and the sum is a simple geometric series.  To finish, evaluate the sum and compute $P_1$  As $I_1=(1+\frac {.06}{12})\times 200000$ we can then read the constant coupon off.

Comment: I understand what you've done, except I'm not sure what a monthly coupon is. What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean the constant payment you make each month.  Sometimes called the "level coupon"...throw back to the old days in which bonds were sometimes printed on paper with actual, physical coupons attached.